# SWRL rule pizza.owl at least two ingredients from the same country

Tags: ontology, swrl

I have extended the original pizza.owl and have now the following SWRL rule in my Protege (Rules editor: Windows/Views/Ontology views/Rules):

```
Pizza(?p), 
hasIngredient(?p, ?ing1), hasIngredient(?p, ?ing2), 
hasCountryOfOrigin(?ing1, ?c1), hasCountryOfOrigin(?ing2, ?c1), 
differentFrom(?ing1, ?ing2) -> NationalPizza(?p)
```

The rule should assert `NationalPizza` for all pizza individuals where at least two ingredients (e.g. PizzaToppings) are from the same country (e.g. `MeatTopping` Lardon_Alsace and `CreamTopping` CrèmeFraîche_Normandie both have `hasCountryOfOrigin` equal to the individual France).
The reasoner (Pellet) finds nothing.
Can I use any swrlb function instead?

+++**EDIT1**+++

I have come up with the following solution:

```
Pizza(?p), 
hasIngredient(?p, ?ing1), hasIngredient(?p, ?ing2), 
hasCountryOfOrigin(?ing1, ?c1), hasCountryOfOrigin(?ing2, ?c1) -> NationalPizza(?p)
```

which gives correct result.

Alternatively, I also tried that way with OWL expressions:

```
Pizza(?p), (hasIngredient min 2 PizzaTopping)(?ing)  -> NationalPizza(?p)
```

but then how do I incorporate the condition that country must be the same? Any ideas?

+++**EDIT2**+++

I made following changes to my SWRL rule (based on @AKSW comment) in the SWRLTab:

```
Pizza(?p) ^ 
hasIngredient(?p, ?i1) ^ hasIngredient(?p, ?i2) ^ 
  hasName(?i1, ?ni1) ^ hasName(?i2, ?ni2) ^ swrlb:notEqual(?ni1, ?ni2) ^ 
hasCountryOfOrigin(?i1, ?c1) ^ hasCountryOfOrigin(?i2, ?c2) ^ 
  hasName(?c1, ?nc1) ^ hasName(?c2, ?nc2) ^ swrlb:equal(?nc1, ?nc2) 
-> NationalPizza(?p)
```

but the Pellet (incremental) reasoner does not assert the individual `BlancheAuxLardonds_MaMère`, which indeed has (at least) two different ingredients (`Lardon_Alsace` and `Reblochon_LEcho-des-Alpages`) from the same country (`France`).

+++**EDIT3**+++

I made following changes in the ontology (based on @AKSW comment):

```
  <rdf:Description>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#AllDifferent"/>
        <owl:distinctMembers rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza#CrèmeFraîche_Normandie"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza#Gorgonzola_Maribor"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza#Lardon_Alsace"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza#Mozzarella_Buffala"/>
            <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza#Reblochon_LEcho-des-Alpages"/>
        </owl:distinctMembers>
    </rdf:Description>
```

Any help on that?

My ontology is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Rhks0ZXBGG_QsnWmpxHRRWrwHQQtpgL/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: First, all these pizzas are modelled as classes, not as individuals in [pizza.owl](https://protege.stanford.edu/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl). Second, Pellet [supports](https://github.com/stardog-union/pellet/wiki/FAQ#does-pellet-support-rules-swrl-which-builtins) the so-called DL-safe rules only. I.e. one can not write something like `subClassOf(?p, Pizza)`. BTW, in SQWRL one can write something like `tbox:sca(?p, Pizza)`. SWRL builtins are rather for working with literals. And what is Lardon Alsace? I can't find this in `pizza.owl`.

Comment: `differentFrom` must be stated explicitly in the ontology...and as StanislavKralin said, there are no individuals unless you added some in your ontology which we don't know.

Comment: @StanislavKralin thank you for your comments. I have added additional explanation to the EDIT part.

Comment: @AKSW yes, I added my individuals. Please see the link to my ontology.

Comment: I have updated the title to better match the content.

Comment: Are you sure that your edited solution works? You did not state that `?ing1` and `?ing2` must be different things, thus, I'd assume that any `Pizza` becomes a `NationalPizza`

Comment: `hasIngredient min 2 PizzaTopping` also needs different individuals. Moreover, you can't express what you want with class expressions, that actually the reason why people extended OWL with rules bymeans of SWRL. OWL class expressions do not have variables and they always describe a tree-like structure only

Comment: @AKSW thanks for your comment. Please, see my new EDIT2 and updated ontology (link). Any new idea?

Comment: It's the first time that you mention the SWRLTab...this plugin doesn't use the Pellet reasoner and inferences are only shown in the tab itslef - it uses the Drools rule engine. If you want to use the Pellet reasoner, you have to add the rule to the ontology via Rules tab. Moreover, individuals in your ontology have be distinct explicitly, i.e. `a owl:differentFrom b`

Comment: @AKSW but you know that it is not possible to enter the swrlb functions in the Rules tab while it is possible to enter them in the SWRLTab and they are visible then in the Rules tab. Anyway, the rule is written to the ontology.  So what is the solution?

Comment: @AKSW I have implemented the `owl:distinctMembers` (see EDIT3). Still no result for my rule....

Comment: No more comments on that?

Comment: You're using the SWRLTab, right? Thus, only the Drools engine will be used. The next step you can do is to debug your rule with the SQWRL Tab. Start with smaller queries and then add another atom to the rule. This helps to understand which atom doesn't match data.